# How to get MVC model strings as plain text in views

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor, html-entities, html-encode

I'm sending a model to a view that have strings.  Those strings are html encoded and I do not need them to be.  Any way to send a model to a view without html encoding?

Model:

```
public class Package
{
    public string String { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult GetPackage()
{
    Package oPackage = new Package();
    oPackage.String = "using lots of \" and ' in this string";
    return View(oPackage);
}
```

View:

```
@model Models.Package
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function () {
        // Here @Model.String has lots of &#39; and &quot;
        var String = "@Model.String".replace(/&#39;/g, "'").replace(/&quot;/g, "\"");
        // Here String looks ok because I run the two replace functions. But it is possible to just get the string clean into the view?
    })();
</script>
```

Running the replace functions is a solution, but just getting the string without the encoding would be great.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
@Html.Raw(yourString)
```

This should work:

```
@model Models.Package
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function () {
      var String = "@Html.Raw(Model.String)";
})();
</script>
```

Comment: This is the correct answer to removing the html encoding.  However, the problem shows itself as there now is too many " in the plain text.  And that screws up the enclosing of the text inside "".  Going back to html encoded text and .replace().

Comment: Because the answer removes what the question asks for "getting the string without the encoding" I find this to be the most accurate answer.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly you need to convert the string to [Javascript format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.javascriptstringencode(v=vs.110).aspx).
Then you need to prevent MVC from re-encoding it as HTML (because its Javascript, not HTML).


So the code you need is:

```
@using System.Web

@model Models.Package

<script type="text/javascript">
    var s = "@Html.Raw(HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(Model.AnyString, addDoubleQuotes: false))";
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

As I think this is different than my previous answer, I am putting here another one. `System.Web.HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(Model.String, true);`

```
@model Models.Package
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function () {
      var String = "@System.Web.HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(Model.String, true)";
})();
</script>
```

Hope this helps.. :)