# Add Script tag to jquery template in mvc 3

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-templates

I am trying to add `<script>` tag to Jquery template as follow

```
<script id="invoiceTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        alert('x');
    </script>        
</script>
```

my problem is in the closing tag of `<script>` element in template. I tried to add this

```
@{
string xs =System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("</script>"));}
    }
<script id="invoiceTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        alert('x');
    @(xs)      
</script>
```

to parse the ending tag and put it as script but the result is like that `&lt;/script&gt;` not `</script>` as expected also my javascript code not working

Comment: why are you putting a a script inside a script? what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am trying to add row template to create a list of rows each row has script functions embedded with it to run with each row

Comment: why dont you create the rows with a specific class + and id to get to it through the script?

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
string xs = @Html.Raw("</script>");
```

like as in [How to get MVC model strings as plain text in views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17104083/how-to-get-mvc-model-strings-as-plain-text-in-views/17106397#17106397)

Comment: that is working but that closes the template script tag and break the template